# Better way to perform AJAX search on large data

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, web

I am new to AJAX and looking for better way to do this. I have search box which searches for string in a array of about 10,000 strings. Code is given below but is way too slow. Of course there is a better way. What is it ?? Here is the HTML and javascript

```
    <script>
    function showHint(str)
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (str.length==0)
      { 
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
      return;
      }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>


    <body>
    <h3>Start typing a name in the input field </h3>
    <form action=""> 
    First name: <input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" />
    </form>
    <p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p> 
    </body>
```

Here is the php code:

```
 include_once("array.php");    //array.php contains array of 10,000 strings

 //get the q parameter from URL
 $q=$_GET["q"];

 //lookup all hints from array if length of q>0
 if (strlen($q) > 0)
   {
   $hint="";
   for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++)
     {
     if (strtolower($q)==strtolower(substr($a[$i],0,strlen($q))))
       {
       if ($hint=="")
         {
         $hint=$a[$i];
         }
       else
         {
         $hint=$hint." , ".$a[$i];
         }
       }
     }
   }

 // Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint were found
 // or to the correct values
 if ($hint == "")
   {
   $response="no suggestion";
   }
 else
   {
   $response=$hint;
   }

 //output the response
 echo $response;
```

Comment: Use a database and the LIMIT clause.

Comment: Have you thought of using a database like MySQL?

Comment: The array of strings have been created after querying about 26 different MySQL databases.

Comment: How many queries will be performed in each request? Did you benchmark those queries?

Comment: 7 queries maximum in each HTTP request. It can differ as per user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After half an hour of chat on IRC someone has convinced me that the best way would be to use a search engine like

- [sphinx search](http://sphinxsearch.com/)
- [elastic search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)